# Purpose of Wrapper function

Tags: c, unix, networking

I am studying Network programming in Unix. What is the purpose is of using wrapper functions for system calls and library calls?

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 good reasons:

1. Wrappers makes it easier port your code to other platforms.

In windows, the socket interface isn't quite identical. With wrappers, you only have to change the code in one place when porting.

2. Wrappers makes it possible to mock system calls for test purposes

By providing mocking code for selected wrappers you can run isolated tests without the need for a full-ledged network environment.